# Xcode iOS simulator's Settings > Bluetooth just spins and doesn't turn on

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, core-bluetooth

I'm trying Apples BTLE Core Bluetooth test app.
But when I run on the iOS Simulator, it doesn't work because Simulator's Settings > Bluetooth was off.

But when I click Settings > Bluetooth to turn it on, it opens the right-hand Bluetooth pane and just shows the busy rotator, and never turns on.

Same problem simulating iPhone or iPad.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION ALREADY:
I just found this Apple Tech note,
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html

If solution, then I will add the answer to this question, so that others may benefit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859451/recommendation-for-bluetooth-le-usb-adapter-for-macbook-air

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about dongles not programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tech note from Apple describes the complete procedure for getting ios simulator to do Bluetooth.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html

I bought the Bluetooth LE USB dongle at Best Buy.  Be sure to ask for one with Bluetooth 4.0 because they still sell 2.0 (cheap).

Comment: Did you ever get it going? I am having the same problem. I have two different BLE 4.0 compliant dongles and have followed Apples steps to get it all going but when on simulated iPhone, I go to settings, Bluetooth is off. If I try to turn it on, I get the spinning wheel of death. I have spent a huge amount of time with Apple supplied developer Apps but can not get by this Apple road block. I could really use some help.

Comment: @Doug Null The link is broken. Did anyone manage to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

This is no longer supported, unfortunately.  (As of Xcode 5.0, iOS7)  The tech note has been taken down and this third-party article describes some of the changes, including loss of BTLE support in the simulator: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/whats-new-in-bluetooth-le-ios-7/