# Discover MFI bluetooth devices in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, ios-simulator, external-accessory

My company signed MFI program so we can now develope application to make communication between external accessories and iPhone via bluetooth (bluetooth 2). In our accessory we have an authentization chip so I can connect to this accessory with iPhone without any problems. iPhone finds this accessory and I can connect to it. My question is if I can find this accessory in iOS simulator in XCode because during searching bluetooth devices simulator can´t find any device. Circle progress bar is spinning but device list is still empty. I have external bluetooth adapter (4 LE) and searching starts but can´t find devices and I tried to switch external adapter with internal one in Mac mini so adapter works. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got answer from Apple:

> The simulator in Xcode doesn't support iAP communication with MFi accessories, not via a USB to 30-pin cable, nor via Classic Bluetooth 2.1+EDR.

Comment: Companies developing MFi hardware sometimes create an OS X .app accessory simulator that works with the iPhone simulator. If this is available, it can be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The devices can only be searched through the iphone or the ipad device as they have the electronic hardware for bluetooth. Whereas the simulator does not have (obvious) it is merely for running your code. Whereas there are some ways like :-

[Xcode iOS simulator's Settings > Bluetooth just spins and doesn't turn on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220953/xcode-ios-simulators-settings-bluetooth-just-spins-and-doesnt-turn-on)

[Is it possible to test an app using Bluetooth in the iOS Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500475/is-it-possible-to-test-an-app-using-bluetooth-in-the-ios-simulator)

Please refer.....

Comment: According to this article: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html it is possible (Bluetooth 4). After plugging bluetooth adapter there is a hardware for simulator, why is bluetooth item in settings in simulator...